Why does a jpg link take up more vertical space than just the jpg?
I have the following code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>testing</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100dvh;
        margin: 0px;
      }

      .wrapper {
        height: 100dvh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
      }

      .content {
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        background-color:yellow;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .footer {
        background-color: red;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-height: 40px;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class = "wrapper">

      <div class = "content">
        content
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <img src="images/email40x40.jpg" height="40" alt="eMail joe">
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>

It works as I would expect with no scrollbar.
If I make the jpg in the footer a link like the following:
  <div class="footer">
    <a href="mailto:joe@someplace.com" title="eMail joe">
      <img src="images/email40x40.jpg" height="40" alt="eMail joe"></a>
  </div>

I suddenly get a scrollbar.  Why is that?  How do I keep it from happening if I want to keep the same footer height.  You can use any 40 jpg to see this behavior.
Thanks, Alan
